# Mongoose group and get sum from two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a PR and Invoices collections and the only common field between them is the customer ID, what I want to achieve is to aggregate and group the two collections to get the sum of the total from the PR and the Invoice collections

PR :

```
const PR = new Schema(
  {
    number: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    customer: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Entity",
    },
    total_usd: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
```

Invoice :

```
const Invoice = new Schema(
  {
    number: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    customer: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Entity",
    },
    total_usd: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
```

I managed to get the sum for each collection seperatly like below :

```
await prModel
      .aggregate([
        { $match: { customer: req.user.entity._id } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "accounts",
            localField: "account",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "account",
          },
        },
        { $unwind: "$account" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              status: "$status",
              account: "$account",
              year: { $year: "$created_at" },
            },
            sum_usd: { $sum: "$total_usd" },
            sum_iqd: { $sum: "$total_iqd" },
          },
        },
      ])
```

but I want to get it for both collections in 1 query

Note: please to ignore the `accounts` lookup in my query

Comment: Can you provide a couple of sample documents from each collection and more of the schemas please? You're looking up `accounts` with a reference to `localField: "account"` and your `customer` field in each schema references `Entity` so we don't have a complete picture in order to help.

Comment: you can ignore the `accounts` lookup, and for the `entity` collection its only have `id, name, and address` fields, what i need is to get the sum of `total_usd` and `total_iqd` for both `PR` and `Invoice` collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { total: { $add: [ "$sum_usd", "$sum_iqd" ] } } }
   ]
)
```

**use the project operator to add those 2 differents fields in the same pipeline**

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want the sum for both collections `PR` and `Invoice` not to add the sum of `total_usd` and `total_iqd`

Comment: @MohammedRiyadh https://mongoplayground.net/p/MK6IlpLo_54 use this as reference to sum to different collection. let me know if there are any issues

Comment: one more question please, can i do group by created_at ?

Comment: yeah you can do for createdAt using gt or lt operators

Comment: please can you visit here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77396067/mongoose-lookup-from-2-collections-gives-wrong-sum-values)